# How to play and install Need For Speed ​​Most Wanted 2012 in Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, wine, playonlinux

I want to install Need For Speed Most Wanted 2012 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS because I can install it in Windows. Ubuntu with Wine/Play on Linux won't open the files.
Someone please help!!! I wanted to install it on Ubuntu with Wine/Play on linux but nothing happens, the game won't open.
How do I make Ubuntu to play Need For Speed ​​Most Wanted 2012?
SOMEONE HELP ME !!!

Comment: I am sorry, but please see this http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/3616/72216 - questions should be asked and responded to in English.

Comment: On Ubuntu 22.04, PlayOnLinux does not work, so I found the alternative to solve the problem: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437380/ubuntu-22-04-how-to-run-an-exe-file-by-the-desktop-shortcut

Answer (score 0):

Buy the game on steam.
Run it on proton 5.1.